# Using a table in Join where one table has all the dates of last three months - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table say as below:

```
Date          Sales_Quantity
 1-JAN-2021      4
 5-JAN-2021      5
15-FEB-2021     10
31-MAR-2021     11
```

What I want is to generate a report on `31-MAR-2021`, displaying all the dates on the left-hand side, for the last three months, and where ever there is no sale display zero.

The result should look like this:

```
1-JAN-2021,4
2-JAN-2021,0
3-JAN-2021,0
4-JAN-2021,0
5-JAN-2021,5
6-JAN-2021,0
...
...
30-MAR-2021,0
31-MAR-2021,11
```

I am guessing I can achieve this by left outer join, but how do I get a left table with all the dates of the last 3 months?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Data you already have:

```
SQL> select * From test;

DATUM       SALES_QUANTITY
----------- --------------
01-jan-2021              4
05-jan-2021              5
15-feb-2021             10
```

Using a CTE, I'm creating a calendar for this year (`sysdate` says so; you can create it for any year, or as many years you want) and outer joining it to the `test` table.

```
SQL> with calendar as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') + level - 1 datum
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 12) -
  5                         trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy')
  6    )
  7  select c.datum,
  8         nvl(t.sales_quantity, 0) sales_quantity
  9  from calendar c left join test t on t.datum = c.datum
 10  order by c.datum;

DATUM       SALES_QUANTITY
----------- --------------
01-jan-2021              4
02-jan-2021              0
03-jan-2021              0
04-jan-2021              0
05-jan-2021              5
06-jan-2021              0
07-jan-2021              0
08-jan-2021              0
09-jan-2021              0
10-jan-2021              0
11-jan-2021              0
<snip>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help...can we create such calendar for last 6 month or so ?

Comment: You're welcome. Sure we can. Exact code depends on what you call "last 6 months".